# How to add nvidia gpu on slurm.conf and gres.conf

Tags: gpu, slurm

I would like to add a first NVIDIA GPU in the slurm cluster and reading I saw that I have to add some info in the slurm.conf, create a gres.conf and more or less this ...

Do you have an example of both files, the part related to the gpu? I'm creating something like this but I do not have idea if it is correct or similar

```
slurm.conf

GresTypes=gpu
Gres=gpu:nvidia:1

gres.conf

NodeName=worker1 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia0
```

What is "File=/dev/nvidia0"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good start, make sure that

- the `Gres=gpu:nvidia:1` is part of a node definition in `slurm.conf`, i.e. on a line starting with `NodeName`
- in `gres.conf` you report the type as well: `NodeName=worker1 Name=gpu Type=nvidia File=/dev/nvidia0`
- you add `gpu` to the list configured as `AccountingStorageTRES` so that the accounting tracks GPU usage as well.

The `/dev/nvidia0` file is the special file through which programs and libraries that use the GPU can communicate with it. It is created on boot, or manually by running the `nvidia-smi` command for instance. See [this nVIDIA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html) for details.